# Как сделать всплывающее окно с запросом пароля?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Вопрос в заголовке. Нужно всплывающее окно при запуске программы с запросом пароля для открытия программы. Пароль верный- показываем основное окно. Не верный- выход.

Answer (score 3):

[При запуске сначала диалог спросит пароль](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c921897039f6b51290bb1b755d0025aa15821efa/pyqt5_simple_check_password.py), а после сделает разные проверки и если все правильно, покажет главное окно:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Example')
        self.setCentralWidget(QLabel('<font size="100">Hello, <b>USER</b>!</font>'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    password, ok = QInputDialog.getText(None, 'Auth', 'Input password:', QLineEdit.Password)
    if not ok:
        QMessageBox.warning(None, 'Warning', 'Need input password!')
        quit()

    if password != '123':
        QMessageBox.warning(None, 'Warning', 'Invalid password!')
        quit()

    w = Example()
    w.show()

    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Более сложные формы авторизации можно сделать вручную, отнаследовавшийсь от `QDialog` и вызывая у виджета не `show`, а [exec](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#exec), очень простой пример:

```
class LoginWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.login = QLineEdit()
        self.login.setPlaceholderText('Введите логин...')

        self.password = QLineEdit()
        self.password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.password.setPlaceholderText('Введите пароль...')

        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow('Login:', self.login)
        layout.addRow('Password:', self.password)

        self.setLayout(layout)
```